# Is the cancellation of blocked file/socket functions guaranteed when a fileno is closed?

Tags: linux, unix, blocking, file-descriptor, cancellation

I read in a lot of place (and sometimes see in code) the idea that closing a file number in some thread of a process will immediately cancel and unblock any I/O blocking call on that file (regular file, socket, or something else) made by another thread.

However I couldn't file either any normative reference guaranteeing that it will happen, or even linux specific documentation that it is the case by design and not by accident.

Is the practice rooted in simple tradition, and inherently unsafe in all cases, or it is somehow guaranteed to work?

(Anyhow, the idea is inherently unsafe in practical multi-threaded code with any part you don't control fully, as you can't know when other threads might re-use that given fileno. I'm not recommending it.)

Comment: Some info from Windows world: this has been done for years in a project I'm working on, before we started using AppVerifier and it has been reported as an error. 

It is actually prohibited by Windows docs - "A Winsock client must never issue `closesocket` concurrently with another Winsock function call" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-closesocket#remarks

If there's run-time analysis tool such as AppVerifier on Linux, maybe it can report it as an error too.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev It's prohibited because it's essentially a race condition on a socket number. It has all the issues of races on system mediated resources (like files), not the issue of data races on scalar accesses though. There are race detectors for linux, but I don't believe they cover those; they are for detecting data races. And yes that pattern which is essentially broken unfixable code (in any non trivial MT context) is disturbingly common and commonly promoted!

Comment: The same place for Linux documentation only refers to this as "_probably unwise_", instead of strict prohibition: It is probably unwise to close file descriptors while they may be in use by system calls in other threads in the same process. Since a file descriptor may be reused, there are some obscure race conditions that may cause unintended side effects.

Comment: In Windows I would use `CancelSynchronousIo` for quick fix of code that uses this pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/cancelsynchronousio-func